# Smart way to handle both "." and "," fraction separator?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, locale

Is there a smart way to handle both "." and "," fraction separator?  I would like to give enduser possibility to input doubles (using Primefaces InputText component) either with "." or "," fraction separator - is that possible?
My native locale is `pl_PL` and my developer's environment (Windows XP) is also configured to target `pl_PL` locale. When I deployed webapp on target server I've noticed validation error when trying to input double values with "," fraction separator. So I defined local in `faces-config.xml` file:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>pl_PL</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>pl_PL</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

and it helped to solve my problem (with configuration like this, decimal part is ignored when saving data with "." fraction separator).

But to meet my initial idea I've tried to configure locale like this:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>pl_PL</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

and it's working properly only with "." fraction separator.

Comment: can you try using `Regular Expressions` ?

Comment: How are you converting your `double` from `String`? Show us your code.